# Postgres pg_terminate_backend alternative

Tags: php, postgresql

I have the following scripts to terminate a backend process.

```
exec('psql -Upostgres -c "select pg_terminate_backend(procpid) from pg_stat_activity where datname= \'' . $databaseName . '\'"');
```

*Note: This script fails on postgres 9.3.10 or above since `procpid` column is replaced with `pid`*

This script is run before I am resetting my database to an earlier state. And if the script fails to run, the next script to reset my database will also fail and throw an error like,

```
ERROR:  column "procpid" does not exist
LINE 1: select pg_terminate_backend(procpid) from pg_stat_activity w...
dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  database "dbName" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  database "dbName" already exists
 Looks like you failed 8 tests of 74.
```

So, I figured an approach to avoid this error by using php script like

```
exec('psql --version', $vout);
$isNewVersion = false;
if ($vout !== false)
{
    $x = preg_match_all('!\d+!', $vout[0], $mcs);
    if ($x !== false && $x > 0) {
        $v = implode('', $mcs[0]);
    }

    // Check if psql version is >= 9.3.10
    $isNewVersion = (strpos($v, '931') !== false);
}
if ($isNewVersion)
{
    exec('psql -Upostgres -c "select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity where datname= \'' . $databaseName . '\'"');
}
else
{
    exec('psql -Upostgres -c "select pg_terminate_backend(procpid) from pg_stat_activity where datname= \'' . $databaseName . '\'"');
}
```

The problem is, I think that my code is not readable or friendly since I am just using this in my `unit testing`.

So, I am wondering if there's another alternative approach where I can terminate a backend that's compatible with any versions of postgres (8.3 or above)

Any advice is appreciated. I am newb in postgres btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both old and new formats of `pg_stat_activity` process id is in the third column,
so you can get it using this query:

```
select (string_to_array(a::text, ','))[3] as pid
from pg_stat_activity a;
```

Comment: I am considering this. Thx alot, It might just be what I am looking for. I'll test it later.

Comment: I guess there's no alternative way to stop a backend. But this another alternative way might actually do it in such simpler way. Thx again.